# What ../path and ~/path Indicates in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, path, html-helper, src

I have one custom helper class called Image which is having two arguments:

1. src
2. alt

Now I am going to call that in one of View,

```
@Html.Image("../Images/Indian.gif","Image is not supported or exist")
<img src="~/Images/Indian.gif" alt="Image is not supported or exist" />
```

Now, this both will give me same result but I am confused that why the path was not the same for both and what "../path" and "~/path" indicate?

This two-line it generates when I do inspect element in a web browser:

```
<img alt="Image is not supported or exist" src="../Images/Indian.gif" />
<img src="/Images/Indian.gif" alt="Image is not supported or exist" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In **ASP.NET**, the tilde `(~)` refers to the application root
>   directory. On the other hand, Two dots `(..)` refers to the folder
>   that is one level higher than the current folder.

When you just use `../` regular paths relative to the web server.Means go up a path from current location (Remember that : `. = This location | .. = Up a directory`).

The `~` character provide virtual paths and refer to the root of the website.

Comment: Thank you but didn't understand this sentence "Two dots (..) refers to the folder that is one level higher than the current folder" @Ashiquzzaman

Comment: When you just use ../ regular paths relative to  the web server.Means  go up a path from current location (`.  = This location | .. = Up a directory`).@DivyeshGausvami

Comment: Okay edit your answer with this description, please @Ashiquzzaman