# Image can load when running by IIS Express on Visual studio, but can't load when running by IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Create Web Application project in `C:\WebApplication1\WebApplication1` as below.
[image]
[image]
The file `Test/index.aspx`

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <h1>index page</h1>
            <img src="../images/myimage1.png" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Image can load when running by IIS Express on Visual studio as below.
[image]

---

Add Application under Default Web Site on IIS and set Default Document to `Test/index.aspx` as below.
[image]
[image]
Image can't load when running by IIS.
[image]
However, I can open the image by `http://localhost/WebApplication1/images/myimage1.png` as below.
[image]
Could you help to suggest me, please?

Comment: Using `..\\` in file path is almost always bad.

Comment: @LexLi, could you help to suggest me for another solution, please?

Comment: On the index page where it doesn't show the image, use the Chrome Developer Tools (F12) to examine the network requests and find the request for the image. Include that path in your question.

Comment: You could also try to set your path like this: `<img src="~/images/myimage1.png" />`. The ~ means the root folder of the web app.

Comment: @agileMike, `~/images/myimage1.png` is not working for me, because the index.aspx is in Test folder.

Comment: @agileMike, I updated output images which are including Inspect element. Please check above,

Comment: @akkapolk you should be able to use the ~ format anywhere. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735333/what-path-and-path-indicates-in-mvc) for an explanation of the ~

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code:

```
<div>
         <h1>index page</h1>
        <img src="./images/myimage1.png" />
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]